# How to get the client IP address inside struts2 action method?

Tags: java, struts2, httprequest

Is there a way to get the client's IP address inside an struts2 action method?

I have implemented both `SesionAware` and `RequestAware` interfaces, but these two inject only the session and request maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [ServletRequestAware](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-can-we-access-the-httpservletrequest.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Try request.getRemoteAddress(). This will give you the client IP. If the request is coming through a proxy server, then you will get only the ip of the proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ServletRequest.getRemoteAddress() API call to get client or last proxy's IP address. This is part of Servlet API and not Struts2 specific.